# (scheme) can define a function but can't call it

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to write a function that calls the map function N times on a list. Its a pretty simple problem:

```
(define (mapNtimes f x L)
  (if (= x 0)
        L
        (mapNtimes (f (- x 1) map (f L)))))
```

Dr Racket is gives me the following error when I try and call my function. Using a statement like this:

```
(mapNtimes ((lambda (x) (* 2 x))) 2 '(1 2 3))
```

It gives me this error

```
    expected: number?
    given: '(3 5 1)
    argument position: 2nd
    other arguments...:
    2
```

I know it something to do with the syntax but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is. Would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are new to Scheme and not familiar with the syntax for invoking Scheme functions.

Given a function `f`, you invoke it using:

```
(f arg1 arg2)
```

not

```
f (arg1 arg2)
```

This works for me.

```
(define (mapNtimes f x L)
  (if (= x 0) L
    (mapNtimes f (- x 1) (map f L))))
```

Comment: it seems like the OP isn't familiar with the syntax of function calls in scheme, could you please mention that `<func>(a b c)` is not a function call, but `(<func> a b c)` is?

Comment: thanks a lot, I just started learning scheme a couple weeks ago for a class. I see now I was passing something very different to my function on the recurse than I thought. Not quite sure how it let me define. Anyway, the corrected version works great. Thanks a lot.